# Which was the first movie to conceal objects in a book?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

**[Concealing objects in book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concealing_objects_in_a_book)** is a popular trope among crime thriller and mystery genre.

To mention a few:

Neo hides cash and disks in a book in **[The Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix)**

[image: Neo hides cash and disks in a book.]

Andy hides hammer in bible.**[The Shawshank Redemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shawshank_Redemption)**

[image: Andy hides hammer in bible.]

Mentioned link lists out movies in which this trope is used.

**But which was the first movie ?**

Comment: There's a TV tropes page for this, although it doesn't give years for the movies: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BookSafe

Comment: This will go back to the old black and white mystery movies of the 1930's & 40s...It's a common trope.

Comment: I think the trope probably predates movies.

Comment: Wikipedia has movies listed starting with *From Russia With Love* in the '60s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concealing_objects_in_a_book

Comment: @ToddWilcox: If you haven't noticed I have mentioned this link in my question but it doesn't say about it being first movie to use trope. It might be possible that the trope predates movies. But there should be a first one to use it.